# Can I use silverlight application in wpf application?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, blend

I got a silverlight sample from http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/ like the analog clock and the progress bar. I am making a wpf desktop application using microsoft blend 4. My problem is how to put/run/embed the sample in my wpf application using the blend 4.

I choose wpf application because I can add windows/form and the codes are almost the same with the windows application form.

and if silverlight is not possible to run in wpf application, can you suggest how to do layered controls? My plan is to run first the loading bar. and then hide it to show the main menu and the analog clock.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is very-very-very compact version of WPF functionality. 
You can just rewrite sample to WPF and it will run more efficient.

Answer (score -2):

Silverlight is just like adobe flex which helps in making(running) web browser apps..
If you use silverlight in your wpf application , then you have to use webbrowser control..

For knowledge:
When we want to try to bring wpf for webbrowser apps we use silverlight..
& doing vice versa(like you are doing), don't make much sense..

Comment: how to use webbrowser control in wpf?